# Validar se a string possui determinado caractere [JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso receber de um input uma string por exemplo "Jose_Silva", como faço para validar se a string possui o "_" nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) - retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência de um valor especificado em uma string, caso contrário retorna `-1`.

```js
var string = "Jose_Silva";
if (string.indexOf('_') > -1)
{
  console.log("contém");
}
```

Pode também usar o método `includes` do ES6

> O método `includes()` determina se uma string pode ser encontrada dentro de outra string, retornando true ou false. O método `includes()` é case sensitive.

```js
var str = 'Jose_Silva';

console.log(str.includes('_'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar expressões regulares,

```
if (/_/.test(minhaStringAProcurar)) {
    alert(minhaStringAProcurar + ' contém _');
}
```

que facilitam a manipulação de string (e a compreensão do código, uma vez que você se acostume a elas). Por exemplo, no caso de obter uma ocorrência de _ na sua string, você provavelmente vai manipulá-la, quebrá-la em partes, ou substituir o caracter por algo,

```
// Com esta linha abaixo, substituo em minhaStringAProcurar
// todas a ocorrências de _ por dólar, e atribuo o resultado
// de volta a minhaStringAProcurar.
minhaStringAProcurar = /_/gm.replace(minhaStringAProcurar, 'dólar')
```

Expressões regulares, como o nome diz, permite que você represente uma cadeia de caracteres em padrões de ocorrência na string bem definidas, com uma linguagem apropriada para isso. É um recurso poderoso, que pode poupar tempo de escrita de código consideravelmente:

```
var resultado = '';
var ocorrenciasDeTextoNoHollerith = /\w+/gm.match(hollerithOriginal)
for (var i = 0; i < ocorrenciasDeTextoNoHollerith.length; ++i) {
    if (resultado !== '') resultado += ', ';
    resultado += ocorrenciasDeTextoNoHolerith[i];
}
alert(resultado);
```

Comment: Se possível explique sua solução